# Aggregate pipeline involving $in

Tags: aggregation-framework, mongodb-3.6.4

We have a shop collection:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
        "shop" : "Q4",
        "batch" : "5647",
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
        "shop" : "Q4",
        "batch" : "2314",
    }
```

First step of aggregation as below:

`Aggregates.group("$shop", Accumulators.addToSet("batch", "$batch"))`

Output:

`{ "_id" : "Q4", "batch" : ["5647", "2314"]}`

Now - given another collection `inventory` as below,we need to find those in  `"batch"` above using `$in` - and add in output

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
        "bolt" : "5647",
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
        "bolt" : "0001",
    }
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
        "bolt" : "0004",
    }
```

Expected output:

```
{ "_id" : "Q4", "batch" : ["5647", "2314"],"bolt":["5647"]}
```

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Do you need a MongoDB query or java converted one ? Also are you looking to achieve these two in one single DB call ?

Comment: Java would be preferable..and they need to be done in a single call.Since the second collection will have ~1M records,tryin to push that entirely into memory for subset is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [conditional `$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries). 
With `$reduce` we convert `bolt:[{...}, {...}]` to `bolt:["...", "..."]`

```
db.shop.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$shop",
      batch: {
        $push: "$batch"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "inventory",
      let: {
        batch: "$batch"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$bolt",
                "$$batch"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bolt"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      batch: 1,
      bolt: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$bolt",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                "$$this.bolt"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wUlecL1KDyR)

Comment: The lookup with $in seems to be taking ages - are index ignored in lookup during aggregation?